# Unable to use a PHP variable column name to update a column in SQL

Tags: php, mysql

```
mysql_query("UPDATE students SET '. $rollno .' = '1'
             WHERE Faculty_id = $id AND date = $date");
```

`$ROLLONO` is the name of the column which doesn't get updated.

Comment: `'. $rollno .'` should be `\` $rollno \``

Comment: Use ticks for the column names...mysql_query("UPDATE students SET \`$rollno\` = '1'
WHERE `Faculty_id` = $id AND \`date\` = '$date' ");

Comment: Be careful if `$rollno = 'Release'` or other reserved words from DB if not used back-ticks.

Answer (score 0):

You are using your PHP variable in magic quotes ("). So no need to keep .

Also in query column name should be either wrapped with ` or nothing.

And values for column name should be in ' or " if they are not int type.

Remove "." and also '. Add ' in date condition

`mysql_query("UPDATE students SET $rollno = '1'
WHERE Faculty_id = $id AND date = '$date'");`

Answer (score 0):

Put date in quotes and setup the correct quotes before $rollno:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE students SET ". $rollno ." = '1'
             WHERE Faculty_id = $id AND date = '$date'");
```

You have double quote before UPDATE: `"`

And single quote after SET: `'`

Which makes your query incorrect.

Date must be in quotes, otherwise it will be treated as integer with minuses.

Comment: hehee... the quotes thing that always make us confused sometimes. :D

Answer (score 0):

You are using single quotes around the column name. You probably don't need them, but if you do, them use a backtick ` caharacter instead for mysql.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE students SET ". $rollno ." = '1'
         WHERE Faculty_id = $id AND date = $date");
```

or

```
mysql_query("UPDATE students SET `". $rollno ."` = '1'
         WHERE Faculty_id = $id AND date = $date");
```

Comment: the dots also are invalid

Comment: @Akam Not if he is trying to break the string :)

Answer (score 0):

- Variables names are case-sensitive.
- It's better to use the concat operator (".")
- The variable must contain the name of the column, not the number

Answer (score 0):

I think you are dynamically using column name and you want :

```
mysql_query("UPDATE students SET ". $rollno ." = '1' WHERE Faculty_id = $id AND date = $date");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$sql = "UPDATE students SET rollno = 1 WHERE Faculty_id = $id AND date = $date "
mysql_query($sql);
```